# The 'refreshToken' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 142) change on every render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to deploy my first React App and i cannot seem to be able to get rid of the following warning which on production stops me from doing a deployment:

Line 60:11:  The 'refreshToken' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 142) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the definition of 'refreshToken' in its own useCallback() Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Is there an easy way to fix this without breaking the JWT token authentification?

AuthContext.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react'
import { API } from "../api"
import axios from "axios"
import { isAfter, isEqual, parseISO, sub } from 'date-fns'

export const AuthContext = React.createContext(null)

export function AuthContextProvider({ children }) {

    const [accessTokenExpiration, setAccessTokenExpiraton] = useState(undefined);

    const getUser = () => {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
    }

    const isLoggedIn = () => {
        return localStorage.getItem('user') !== null
    }

    const [user, setUser] = useState(() => {
        return isLoggedIn() ? getUser() : null;
    })

    const [shouldGoToLogin, setShouldGoToLogin] = useState(() => {
        if (!user || !user.access_token || !user.refresh_token) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    })

    const logout = async () => {
        if (!user) {
            return;
        }

        const { access_token } = user;
        localStorage.removeItem('user')
        setUser(null);

        return axios.post(API.auth.logout, {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${access_token}`,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            withCredentials: true
        });
    }
    
    const login = async (values) => {
        console.log(values);
        const correctedValues = { ...values, username: values.email };
        return axios.post(API.auth.login, correctedValues)
            .then(res => {
                const data = res.data;
                processApiData(data);
            })
    }
    const processApiData = useCallback((resp) => {
        let newUser = { ...user, ...resp };
        delete(newUser.user); // Delete the user sub-object since we merged that directly into the top-level object
        saveUser(newUser); // Save the user

        const { access_token_expiration } = newUser;

        if (access_token_expiration) {
            console.log("have expiration", access_token_expiration);
            const nextExpiration = parseISO(access_token_expiration); // Convert from ISO 8601 to a Date Object
            const earlyRefreshTime = sub(nextExpiration, { minutes: 55 }); // Do an hourish early
            setAccessTokenExpiraton(earlyRefreshTime); // Set the upcoming expiraton
        }
    }, [user])
    const refreshToken = useCallback(async () => {
        const user = getUser();

        const redirectToLogout = () => {
            localStorage.clear(); // Clear our localStorage
            setShouldGoToLogin(true);
        };

        if (!user) { // No user
            redirectToLogout();
        }

        console.log(API.auth.refreshToken);
        const resp = await fetch(API.auth.refreshToken, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({'refresh': user?.refresh_token}),
            method: "POST",
            withCredentials: true
        })

        console.log("status", resp.status);
        if (resp.status === 200) {
            const data = await resp.json(); // Convert to JSON
            console.log("refresh token data", data);
            processApiData(data);
        } else {
            redirectToLogout();
        }
    }, [processApiData])

    const resetPassword = async (values) => {
        return axios.post(API.auth.passwordReset, values);
    }



    const saveUser = async (newUser) => {
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(newUser))
        setUser(newUser)
    }

    const signup = async (values) => {
        return axios.post(API.auth.signup, values);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        
        if (!user) {
            return;
        }

        const interval = setInterval(()=> {
            if(!user){
                return false;
            }

            if (accessTokenExpiration) {
                const now = new Date(); // Get the current time
                console.log(now);
                console.log(accessTokenExpiration);
                if (isAfter(now, accessTokenExpiration) || isEqual(now, accessTokenExpiration)) { // If we are late to the party or the stars have aligned
                    refreshToken(); // Refresh the token
                }
            } else { // We do not have an access token expiration yet
                refreshToken(); // Refresh the token immediately so we get a time
            }
        }, 1000 * 15)
        return ()=> clearInterval(interval)
    }, [accessTokenExpiration, refreshToken, user])

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{
            getUser,
            isLoggedIn,
            logout,
            login,
            resetPassword,
            signup,
            user,
            shouldGoToLogin
        }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put refreshToken function directly in your useEffect hook or wrap in useCallback.

Comment: I tried that but it gave me another error: Line 144:32:  'refreshToken' is not defined. I put the function inside the useEffect hook

Comment: Can you edit your post and show us how you did it?

Comment: Edited it with what i tried

Comment: If you move the function inside the useEffect hook it's not any more in the outer scope. Please remove it from the dependency array of useEffect hook: ```[accessTokenExpiration, refreshToken, user]```

Comment: I got a few more issues when i did that so i used the callback instead as you suggested. I edited my question above. I'm not sure if the way i did it is the proper way but the errors are gone and everything seems to be working still.